# Null Pointer Exception when writing to a File - Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, nullpointerexception

My app crashes every time I go to send the data gathered by the sensor. The error I am given is as follows:

```
06-20 14:50:00.784  22983-22983/com.example.adam.proj2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.adam.proj2.SensorActivity.onClick(SensorActivity.java:124)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code for gathering the sensor data:

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float x = event.values[0];
    ArrayList<Float> enrolAcc = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Float> authAcc = new ArrayList<>();
    TextView textEnrol = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    if (choice == 1) {
        mPreviousAcc = mCurrentAcc;
        mCurrentAcc = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x * x));
        float delta = mCurrentAcc - mPreviousAcc;
        mDiffAcc = mDiffAcc * 0.9f + delta;
        if (enrolAcc.size() < 100) {
            enrolAcc.add(x);

        } else {
            enrolAcc.remove(0);
            enrolAcc.add(x);
        }
        walkData = enrolAcc.toString();
        textEnrol.setText(walkData);
    }
```

Here is the code for writing to the file (this happens onClick of a button):

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.enrolBtn:
            choice = 1;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enrolment Mode Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.authBtn:
            choice = 2;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication Service Starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.sendBtn:
            choice = 3;
            String baseDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            String fileName = "Walk Data.csv";
            String filePath = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;
            File f = new File(filePath);
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                out.write(walkData.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            android.net.Uri u1 = Uri.fromFile(f);
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u1);
            sendIntent.setType("text/html");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
            break;
    }
}
```

From what I can see the exception is generated by the out.write method?
The array list holding the sensor values is stored in the walkData string so that the string can be then written in the csv file stored on the external device storage. I would like the data to be in CSV format.

I am stumped and cannot figure out how to prevent this, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: judging from the stack-trace we need to see this part of the code : com.example.adam.proj2.SensorActivity.onClick(SensorActivity.java:124)

Comment: The exception is thrown in SensorActivity.onClick(), at line 124. You didn't post that method, and didn't say which line was line 124.

Comment: line 124 is this line in the onClick method: out.write(walkData.getBytes());                                                                      I have also updated to include the full onClick method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you are trying to write to a `READ ONLY` file.
The line `out = new FileOutputStream(f)` throws an exception:
  `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/Walk Data.csv: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)`, but you actually ignore it, so `out = NULL` and then you get the other exception.
Move your file to a place where you can write to it -

```
    String fileName = "Walk Data.csv";
    String baseDir = getFilesDir() + "/" + fileName;
    File f = new File(baseDir);
```

Comment: I have implemented the changes you suggest above and this has allowed the file to be written to with no issues although this has caused another error which does not enable the email to send. I have edited the question and the new error is at the bottom of the question.

Comment: 1. I can't guess what is your "another error". Unless you provide more details, nobody can't help you.  2. you've asked for help for a specific error. If any of the above answers solved your problem, accept it and ask a new question.

Comment: My "another error" is displayed at the bottom of the question? Thanks, I will make this a new question then.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code:

```
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.write(walkData.getBytes());
```

The exception is thrown at the last line. So, what could possibly be wrong at that line?

`out` could be null. `out` **will** be null if the file is not found, since you catch that exception and pretend nothing wrong happened at the line before, leaving `out` as null. You shouldn't try to use `out`if you just failed to initialize it. The try block should ensclose all the lines using `out`, and not just the line initializing it.

`walkData`could also be null. But since we don't know where it comes from, we can't say. Use your debugger to know which is null. And whatever the answer is, fix your exception handling code. It should look like

```
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            out.write(walkData.getBytes());

            android.net.Uri u1 = Uri.fromFile(f);
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u1);
            sendIntent.setType("text/html");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO signal the error to the user. Printing a stack trace is not enough
        }
        finally {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO signal the error to the user. Printing a stack trace is not enough
                }
             }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have moved all of of the lines using out into one try block and I no longer receive an error. However the attached CSV file in the email is not containing any of the sensor data and is empty?

Comment: You no longer receive an error because you probably haven't implemented the TODOs in my answer. Also, don't continue as if nothing happened after you caught an exception.

Comment: Apologies, I am new to Java, what do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean that if there was an error when writing to the file, you shouldn't try to send the file. You should instead tell the user "Hey, something wrong happened".